# Eclipse: "Show console view" failing at application start

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been having this problem on/off for the last few days:

I start up Eclipse and try to debug my Java Application from the debug button at the top (the bug next to the "play" icon). The application starts, but after a while this pop up is displayed:

[image: Show Console View error pop up]

If I open the debug view I can see the application and all the threads are running, I can make requests to the application (it's a web server) and it's working fine. But the console view looks like this:

[image: Broken Console View]

When it should contain a toolbar and have printed some output.

I can stop and restart the application, and the same thing happen. It makes no difference whether I "run" or "debug" the application, or where I start it from (debug menu, debug view, package explorer, F11, etc).

The only way I can fix the problem is to close Eclipse and open it again. It seems to normally work the second time I open it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to close Eclipse to fix the issue. Just close "Console" tab from views, go to Windows -> Show View -> Console. Sometimes the listener code for Console view gets crazy and start throwing exceptions.

Hope it helps.

PS: This fix works for Eclipse and STS

Comment: +1: Can't test it at the moment, but this sounds quite useful, even if it doesn't fix the issue (perhaps there is no fix) :)

Comment: I tried your way, it didn't work. I restarted and error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when all the things are not completely ready to open in your eclipse. The only fix I found is , Save your files and restart the eclipse.

In Eclipse main menu go to File->Restart. your problem should be fixed now. your program is ready to run